# Mysql find keywords in text

Tags: mysql, string, match, keyword

I have a Mysql InnoDB table with 10k keywords and I want to match them against several texts.

Some keywords have several words and I only want exact matchs.

Example:
Keywords - brown fox, lazy cat, dog, fox, rabbit

Text - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

I want the query to return - brown fox, dog, fox

Comment: I have 10k keywords. I cannot go one by one.

Comment: The example you give is the oposite of what I need. The idea was to go something like full text SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'); the problem is that the table is InnoDB and doesn't work with full text and full text doesn't return only full match. It would also return partial matchs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tenKTable 
WHERE 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' LIKE CONCAT('%',keyword,'%')
```

Source: [MySQL SELECT query string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916195/mysql-select-query-string-matching)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea:

```
SELECT keyword 
FROM Keywords
 JOIN (SELECT 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' as col) k
   on k.col like Concat('%',keywords.keyword,'%')
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71c80/4).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very good. An improvement would be

```
SELECT kw FROM keyword
WHERE ' text ' LIKE CONCAT('% ',kw,' %')
```

Remember to prepend and append space to the text. This way, you avoid partial matches altogether.